# NSDateFormatter to Int in Swift

Tags: swift, int, nsdate

I am trying to convert a NSDateFormater Int, but the variables return nil. 
This is the code I'm using:

```
    var datePeriodBegin:NSDate = NSDate()    
    if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("datePeriodBegin") != nil){
        datePeriodBegin = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("datePeriodBegin")! as? NSDate)!
    }

    let datePeriodEnd = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth, value: 6, toDate: datePeriodBegin, options: nil)!


    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd000000"

    var start:Int = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePeriodBegin).toInt()!
    var end:Int = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePeriodEnd).toInt()!

    println(start) // return nil in iPhone 4S -> iPhone 5s
```

Comment: It returns `nil` when you run this on a device only? Because I just pasted it in a Playground and *it works*.

Comment: Can also confirm it works for me as written in a playground.

Comment: Your code is unsafe in case the platform uses 32 bit Int, 'cause you're going over `Int32.max`. Anyway you might be safer making your calculation in another way. Maybe using explicitly date components and 64 bit Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date does not fit into [Int32](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/NumericTypes.html). iPhone 4s is 32 bit, iPhone 5s should be 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yene is absolutely correct, if you really need all those zeroes on the end then on a 32-bit device you need to convert to Int64 first:

```
  var datePeriodBegin:NSDate = NSDate()
        if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("datePeriodBegin") != nil){
            datePeriodBegin = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("datePeriodBegin")! as? NSDate)!
        }

        let datePeriodEnd = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth, value: 6, toDate: datePeriodBegin, options: nil)!


        var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

        var start = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePeriodBegin).toInt()
        var end = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePeriodEnd).toInt()

        if let s = start {
            println(Int64(s)*1000000) // return 20150427000000 iPhone 4S -> iPhone 5
        }
```

On a 32-bit device the maximum value of an Int is the same as an Int32, which is 2147483647, whereas the maximum value of an Int64 is 9223372036854775807 (the same as an Int on a 64-bit device).

**Update: iOS 9, Xcode 7**

The code no longer works with current version of Xcode and Swift - here is the working code rewritten for iOS 9, Xcode 7:

```
var datePeriodBegin:NSDate = NSDate()
if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("datePeriodBegin") != nil){
    datePeriodBegin = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("datePeriodBegin")! as? NSDate)!
}

let datePeriodEnd = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Month, value: 6, toDate: datePeriodBegin, options: [])!


var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

var start = Int(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePeriodBegin))
var end = Int(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePeriodEnd))

if let s = start {
    print(Int64(s)*1000000) // return 20150427000000 iPhone 4S -> iPhone 5
}
```

If it breaks in a future version of Xcode/Swift/iOS please comment and I'll update.